# Tinypass embed code issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing `ROR application` and using `Tinypass gem` for payment.

I integrated tinypass and its work very well. But display price is static as I wrote in page not fetch from `tinypass account prices` which I set.

Now, I want to display that dynamic price. So, as per `tinypass account` give me `embed code` to put into `<head>` in our site template so its work auto.

But its now work for me and `nothing display`. Any one have a solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The display price should be dynamic per your dashboard. The embed code injected into  would do this if it's your only integration. If on full API or combining API and V2 of plugin, then the price change would be static.

For more info, contact support here with your AID: support@tinypass.com